# NSLayoutConstraint negative multiplier gives unexpected results

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

We are using `Xcenter` and `Ycenter` `NSLayoutConstraint` to position `subview` inside parent `superview`. As we need to keep the position proportional we can't use the `constant` value of the constraints to position it, it needs to be based purely on the multiplier.

The `subview` can be a position outside of the `superview` bounds so a negative multiplier is needed. The thing is that when we apply a negative multiplier (via code) the subview position is moving in an unexpected way. Using the auto layout formula it seems to be possible, but in practice, it's not. Here is a visualization:

[image]

After Setting the width/height constraints I'm settings the X and Y ones like this:

```
let xAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: multpliers.x, constant: 0)        
xAnchor.isActive = true

let yAnchor = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: multpliers.y, constant: 0)
yAnchor.isActive = true
```

Only when the multiplier is negative we get unexpected results.

**Does anyone has a hint abound what's going on with negative multipliers? We are stuck on this for a few good old days...**

Comment: Can you show the exact constraint code / setup in storyboard please?

Comment: @AndréSlotta Added the code, we aren't using storyboards/xibs, code only.

Comment: I guess you have to show some more code since when I implement it like this everything works as expected. Can you show a bit more of your view hierarchy? Where and when exactly do you create those constraints?

Comment: Hey @AndréSlotta, I've sent you an email.